# Circle-like shape recognition

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I am trying to build a program that can segment the area within these circle-like shapes. All the images will have a white background, and 5 experimental conditions that consist of either red or yellow color circular-like shaped liquids. For instance,

[Yellow image - original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecngQ.png)

[Red image - original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0d2P.jpg)

I want to extract the regions within the 5 round-ish circles to do further analysis, but I am stuck in this first step.

What I want is something like this
[Yellow image - output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSgsY.jpg)
This is circled out manually, but I want a program that can do this automatically.

I have tried using cv2's find contours and hough circles, but for find contours, perhaps the colors of my experimental conditions are not too drastically different from white, so it cannot detect the contours accurately. And for hough circles, it can only detect perfect circles, so my circle-ish shapes cannot be detected.
[Example -- red using find contours (not defined outline)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3VT6.jpg)
[Example -- red using hough circles (can only detect perfect circles)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I7IY.png)

Here is the code for my find contours

```
image= cv2.imread('red.jpg')

gray= cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edges= cv2.Canny(gray,30,200)

contours, hierarchy= cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0,255,0),3)

cv2.imshow('All Contours', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Code for hough circles

```
experiment = cv2.imread('red.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(experiment, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)

cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 120, param1 = 100, param2 = 30, minRadius = 0, maxRadius = 0)
circles = np.uint(np.around(circles))

for i in circles[0, :]:
    cv2.circle(experiment, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("Detection results", experiment)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What should I do? Perhaps, I am thinking I can just simply remove all the white background, but how can I do that and how do I save each cropped experimental condition into its own file subsequently?

Comment: If you can threshold or edge detect and then get contours, then you might try using cv2.fitEllipse.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to grayscale
- Blur
- Divide the gray image by the blurred image to do division normalization (whiten the background)
- Stretch the normalized image to full dynamic range
- Do adaptive thresholding
- Apply morphology close to connect the boundaries of the circles
- Get the external contours
- Loop over the contours filtering out those smaller than some area threshold, then fit the remaining contours to ellipses, print the ellipse parameters, draw the contours on a copy of the input and also draw the ellipses on a copy of the input
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

# read the input
img = cv2.imread('circles5.jpg')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# blur
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (0,0), sigmaX=99, sigmaY=99)

# do division normalization
normal = cv2.divide(gray, blur, scale=255)

# stretch to full dynamic range
stretch = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(normal, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)

# adaptive threshold
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 25, 6)

# apply morphology close
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11,11))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get external contours
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

# filter out small contours and fit ellipse
# draw contour on copy of image and also draw ellipse
result1 = img.copy()
result2 = img.copy()
i = 1
for cntr in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cntr)
    if area > 10000:
        ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cntr)
        (xc,yc),(d1,d2),angle = ellipse
        print('ellipse #:', i)
        print('center:', xc,yc)
        print('diameters:', d1,d2)
        print('angle:', angle)
        print('')
        cv2.drawContours(result1, [cntr], 0, (0,0,255), 1)
        cv2.ellipse(result2, (int(xc),int(yc)), (int(d1/2),int(d2/2)), angle, 0, 360, (0,0,255), 1)
        i = i + 1

# save results
cv2.imwrite('circles5_division_normalized.jpg', normal)
cv2.imwrite('circles5_stretched.jpg', stretch)
cv2.imwrite('circles5_thresholded.jpg', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('circles5_morph.jpg', morph)
cv2.imwrite('circles5_contours.jpg', result1)
cv2.imwrite('circles5_ellipses.jpg', result2)

# show results
cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
cv2.imshow('blur', blur)
cv2.imshow('normalized', normal)
cv2.imshow('stretched', stretch)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('morph', morph)
cv2.imshow('contours', result1)
cv2.imshow('ellipses', result2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Normalized Image:

[image]

Stretched Image:

[image]

Adaptive Thresholded Image:

[image]

Morphology Closed Image:

[image]

Contours on Input:

[image]

Ellipses on Input:

[image]

Ellipse Parameters:

```
ellipse #: 1
center: 798.6463012695312 267.5460510253906
diameters: 145.31993103027344 159.45236206054688
angle: 91.30252075195312

ellipse #: 2
center: 1036.6676025390625 252.74435424804688
diameters: 141.51364135742188 151.05157470703125
angle: 138.46131896972656

ellipse #: 3
center: 344.023681640625 241.0209197998047
diameters: 137.6905517578125 141.6817626953125
angle: 143.69598388671875

ellipse #: 4
center: 99.26034545898438 250.16726684570312
diameters: 146.94293212890625 160.36122131347656
angle: 166.9673614501953

ellipse #: 5
center: 585.333251953125 231.5453338623047
diameters: 130.96046447753906 175.29257202148438
angle: 143.37709045410156
```